# Add-Computer command failing to work with error: RPC Server is Unavailable

Tags: powershell, dns

Just testing out creating a new PS script for our IT team to use which will remove a computer remotely from the domain and then re-add it using the Add-Computer command.

The 3 lines of code are:

```
$Hostname = Read-Host "Please enter the computers hostname that you wish to remove and re-add to the domain"
Remove-Computer -ComputerName "$Hostname" -UnjoinDomainCredential "DOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -PassThru -Verbose - Restart
Add-Computer -ComputerName "$Hostname" -LocalCredential "$Hostname\ukitadmin" -Credential "DOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -DomainName "DOMAIN" -Force -Verbose -Restart
```

Just to clear the air. The env:USERNAME command is using the account I've run PS ISE as, so will be my admin account.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: "RPC Server is Unavailable" means "I couldn't connect to the computer". One guess would be windows firewall rules that are different for public networks vs domain networks.

Answer (score 0):

You restart the computer with the second command, so when the third command tries to run, the computer is unavailable.

you can do this with your code, it should wait for the computer to finish restarting

I removed the -restart from the remove-computer command

```
$Hostname = Read-Host "Please enter the computers hostname that you wish to remove and re-add to the domain"

Remove-Computer -ComputerName $Hostname -UnjoinDomainCredential "DOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -PassThru -Verbose 

Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Hostname -Wait

Add-Computer -ComputerName $Hostname -LocalCredential "$Hostname\ukitadmin" -Credential "DOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -DomainName "DOMAIN" -Force -Verbose -Restart
```